# Proof for association law?

Tags: discrete-mathematics, logic, propositional-calculus, associativity

I am new in logic and I getting a little bit confused with maths. Can I do something like this following the **Associative Law**?

$$(p ∨ ¬r) ∨ (r ∨ ¬p) ≡ (p ∨ ¬p) ∨ (r ∨ ¬r)$$

Thank you in advance for your help

Comment: Yes, the logical operator $\lor$ is associative and commutative, so you can do it. Your working is correct. Do note that what you did is not just use "associativity" but also "commutativity" since you rearranged the propositions in the statement (switched the places of $\neg r$ and $\neg p$).

Comment: Yes of course, thank you for your quick reply!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Always go back to the (intuitive) intended meaning of the logical symbols. "$P \lor Q$" is true exactly when either "$P$" or "$Q$" is true (or both), which is also equivalent to that at least one of "$P$" or "$Q$" is true.

Now it is then clear that $( P \lor Q ) \lor R$ is going to be true exactly when at least one of $P,Q,R$ is true, and the order and arrangement do not matter.